# Exception when reading empty cells from Excel file

Tags: java, excel, exception, cell, jxl

When trying to read an Excel sheet I get an exception if some cell is empty:

```
Cell[] rowCells = sheet.getRow(1);
```

or

```
Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0,1);
```

I always get the same message:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
    at gui.ReadExcel.read(ReadExcel.java:45)
    at gui.GUIcontroller.chooseSaveFile(GUIcontroller.java:101)
```

What is the problem? How can I know if the cell is empty, so I won't copy its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getRows` or `getColumns` method to check the bounds of the `sheet`. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs because you are trying to access a value, which is beyond the range of the farthest cell which is not empty.

```
int rows = sheet.getRows();
int columns = sheet.getColumns();
int i = 1;
if(i<rows)
    Cell[] rowCells = sheet.getRow(i);  //Won't throw an Exception

if(i<rows && j<columns)
    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i,j);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't read the cell because, as far as jxl is concerned, it doesn't really exist on the spreadsheet. It has yet to be created so there is really no cell to get. It may sound odd because excel sheets go on for what seems like forever though it doesn't store the data of all these empty cells because the file size would be huge. So when jxl goes to read the data it will simply tell you there is nothing there.

If you want to read the cells and all your cells are grouped together than you could try:

```
int width = sheet.getColumns();
int height = sheet.getRows();

List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<height; j++){
  cells.add(sheet.getCell(i, j));
 }
}
```

If they're not grouped together and your not sure which cells maybe empty there is still a fairly simple solution

```
List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
Cell cell = null;
try{
  cell = sheet.getCell(0, 1);
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
  if(cell != null){
    cells.add(cell);
  }
}
```

This way you can safely attempt to read a cell and throw it away if it doesn't contain anything.

I hope this is what you were looking for.